# Is throwing exceptions for user generated errors considered abuse?

Tags: php, exception

Suppose I have a form that lets a user register for a site, and there are three EXPECTED errors they can get:

1. Username is already taken
2. Email is already taken
3. Password does not meet minimum requirements

If I throw exceptions for these, and then handle them gracefully in a try/catch, is that considered good practice, or abuse of exceptions?

I feel like there's a difference between using exceptions to display known/expected messages to end-users, and using exceptions to alert developers as to issues with the code when developing something.

It's very tempting to use exceptions and try/catch blocks as an easy solution to displaying user-facing messages (even success confirmations!). Where is the use/abuse line concerning exception messages (if any)?

Comment: I dont think this is abuse, it keeps your code pretty small and fast. I usually use this try/catch idea with the exceptions too for a lot of user generated errors and usually i have no problem with it.

Comment: I would only use exceptions with try/catch as @YUNOWORK pointed out. It is not abuse of it. If you had javascript validation and or ajax too, you could skip the round-trip and exceptions for it

Answer (score 0):

Success confirmations are not exceptions, that's actually the essence of the word `exception`. i.e.: an exception occurs because the functionality does not end with success.

This is definitely not abusive to raise an exception for any of the situations you mention. I personnally would even say that it is a good practice, since it enforces use cases encapsulation at the highest level (try catch at service interface or front-end level)